# Как получить id из предыдущий и следующие div через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить id из предыдущий и следующие div через js? А если закончилось то выполняем `alert('Закончилось!');`

```js
/* PREV */
$(".prev").on("click", function() {
  $("div.active:not(:first-child)").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active").click();
});
/* NEXT */
$(".next").on("click", function() {
  $("div.active:not(:last-child)").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active").click();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #EEE;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #555;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
div.active {
  background: #555;
  color: #FFF;
}
button {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
}
button:hover {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  Block 1
</div>
<div id="2" class="active">
  Block 2
</div>
<div id="3">
  Block 3
</div>
<button class="prev">
  Предыдущий id 1
</button>
<button class="next">
  Следующий id 3
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните div'ы в общий контейнер и перепишите селекторы для `.prev()` и `.next()`, чтобы искал внутри этого контейнера. Тогда для первого элемента [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) вернёт пустой jQuery-объект. То же для последнего и `.next()`.

Но лучше заранее знать все id элементов – напр., держать их в массиве. Сохранять в переменной значение "текущего", и по нажатии на кнопки вперёд/назад менять значение этой переменной, если возможно. И перерисовывать стили, раз пробежавшись по всем, или только поменяв бывший текущий и новый.